# How to Change column datatype in databricks delta table

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

%sql
ALTER TABLE  TableName alter  COLUMN ColName int

Error:

```
ParseException: 
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'int': extra input 'int'.(line 1, pos 68)

== SQL ==
ALTER TABLE  TableName  alter  COLUMN ColName int
```

--------------------------------------------------------------------^^^

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE TableName CHANGE COLUMN ColName ColName int;